# PostgreSQL script error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am getting this error. Why?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION factuurRegel()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$$

BEGIN
INSERT INTO Factuur(factuurnr, factuurdatum, bestelnr)
VALUES ((default to_char(CURRENT_DATE ,'yyyy') || '-' || new.bestelnr), CURRENT_DATE, new.bestelnr);
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Error:

```
    ERROR:  syntax error at or near "default"
LINE 7: VALUES ((default to_char(CURRENT_DATE ,'yyyy') || '-' || new...
                 ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "default"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 137
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a postgresql guy, but I'm 99% sure you can't put `default` inside `VALUES()` and also include a value there.  I think you want this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION factuurRegel()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$$

BEGIN
INSERT INTO Factuur(factuurnr, factuurdatum, bestelnr)
VALUES ((to_char(CURRENT_DATE ,'yyyy') || '-' || new.bestelnr), CURRENT_DATE, new.bestelnr);
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[See here for more info](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html) - you can include DEFAULT as a value *or* provide a value, but not both.

Comment: Worked thanks, will accept soon. I am also not into postgresql. Straight from hell if you ask me. But we have to use this for our project at the moment.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: that's what I thought at first, too. Scroll right; there are three total.

Comment: @EdCottrell: Ah, I see now, sorry. Took the liberty to remove some white space and removed my misguided comment. Well, and fixed the link to point to the current manual. 8.2 is rather outdated.